# Get possible datatypes for preparedStatement - Java DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement

Is there any way to get the datatypes accepted by a `PreparedStatement` before inserting values?

The Scenario is I am getting Excel (or OpenOffice) Docs, which I parse to import the data into a database. Sometimes if a numeric 0 is meant, the cell in Excel is left empty. 
Is there a way to get the column type from a prepared insert statement, to be sure to which datatype I have to parse the value?

I think this should be very well possible by runnning a select statement on the tables beforehand and just look at the ResultSet metadata. But if possible I'd like to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` doesn't support it. It will let you set any datatype, but when you will execute the query, that's when for datatype mismatch you will get `SQLException`.
 You best bet is to use SYSTEM CATALOG views to identify column datatype, and set/derive values accordingly. 
DB2 has this view `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` to get you what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameter metadata from the prepared statement and it contains among other things the parameter data types.

```
ParameterMetaData metadata = preparedStatement.getParameterMetaData();
int type = metadata.getParameterType(col);
```

Java doc [getParameterMetaData()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html#getParameterType(int))

Comment: That's what I wrote about in the question and wanted to try to get around.

Comment: @guitarjunk Oh, you need parameter metadata not column. My bad. I update my answer